# Error in deploying SQL CLR

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Error1:

> The following error might appear if you deploy a SQL CLR project that was built for a version of the .NET Framework that is incompatible with the target instance of SQL Server: "Deploy error SQL01268: CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly failed because assembly failed verification". To resolve this issue, open the properties for the project, and change the .NET Framework version.

Error2:

> Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6503, Level 16, State 12, Line 1 Assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=3.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' was not found in the SQL catalog.
>     An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

Comment: Have you tried this: **To resolve this issue, open the properties for the project, and change the .NET Framework version**

Comment: Yeah I have changed the .Net Framework version to 3.5 from 4.0 .But still the error is coming

Comment: Got it the problem .Have to install System.ServiceModel in Sql Server 2008

Comment: If that was the solution, please answer yourself, and accept as answer to make it useful for other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to install System.ServiceModel in Sql Server 2008 and it worked after that.
Happy Coding :)